# php shopping cart deleting an item

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I am trying to build a shopping cart for a PHP project, however, I have ran into a problem. When I add items to the cart session, I have them displayed in a cart summary.

> Item 1 
>  Item 2 
>  Item 3

Whenever I delete an item, the other items below it deletes.
For example, if I delete **Item 2 then Item 3** deletes, as well. 
If I delete 
**Item 1,
Items 2 and 3** deletes, too.

#### update-cart.php

```
<code>

if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{

$prod_id    = $_GET["removep"]; 
$return_url     = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); 
foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
{

if($cart_itm["prod_id"]!=$prod_id)
{
$products[] = array('prod_name'=>$cart_itm["prod_name"],'prod_id'=>$cart_itm["prod_id"], 'prod_price'=>$cart_itm["prod_price"], 'prod_percent'=>$cart_itm["prod_percent"], 'prod_qty'=>$cart_itm["prod_qty"]);
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["products"] = $products;
}

}
header('Location:'.$return_url);
}

</code>
```

#### widget_summary.php

```
<code>



if(isset($_SESSION['products']))
 {
 $total = 0;
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
 {
 $new_price = discount($cart_itm["prod_price"], $cart_itm["prod_percent"]);
 echo '<table class="cart-items">';
 echo    '<tr>';
 echo        '<td>'.$cart_itm["prod_name"].'</td>';
 echo        '<td><span class="remove-item right"><a href="update-cart.php?    removep='.$cart_itm["prod_id"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">&times;</a></span></td>';
 echo    '</tr>';
 echo    '<tr>';
 echo        '<td id="qty">Qty: '.$cart_itm["prod_qty"].' &times;    $'.$new_price.' = </td>';
            $sub = $cart_itm["prod_qty"] * $new_price;
echo        '<td class="right subtotal">$'.number_format($sub,2).'</td>';
echo    '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
        $subtotal = ($new_price*$cart_itm["prod_qty"]);
        $total = number_format($total + $subtotal, 2);
}

echo '<table class="tbl-summary-footer">';
echo '<tr>';
echo    '<td> Total </td>';
echo    '<td><span class="price_now right"><strong>$'.$total.'</strong>  </span></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo    '<td><span class="empty-cart"><a href="update-cart.php?emptycart=1&return_url='.$current_url.'">Clear Cart</a></span></td>';
echo    '<td><span class="right"><a href="shopping-cart.php">Check-out!</a></span></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</ul>';
}
else
{
echo 'Cart is empty.';
}

</code>
```

Comment: Try declaring $products before the loop, you should also only need to set the session products key after the loop

Comment: Check your loop, it's already creating a new `<table>`element for each product stored in `$_SESSION`

Comment: Your logic is flawed, you only write your “new” $products array into the session when your loop reaches the id in question – and therefor the following products, that you only add to the array afterwards, do not get put into the session at all. // Your whole approach here is convoluted and kinda nonsense. Use the product id as array key – then you only have to unset the entry with that key from your array, nothing else; and you can do it directly “in” $_SESSION, without having to copy that data around.

Comment: (And I hope you are only doing this for personal learning/educational purposes … because with the level of knowledge that you’re displaying here, I don’t think you are ready to programm a system that is suitable for production use.)

Comment: @mr12086 Thank you so much, I set the session after the loop and everything is deleting correctly now.

Comment: @CBroe yes, sorry about the code, I am doing this for personal learning. Thank you for your suggestions. I will continue to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare $products before the foreach loop.
You will need to set the session key 'products' after the loop.